# Sequences of positive integers $(a_{k})_{k \in \omega}$ that only give finitely many zeros modulo $p_{k}$ in total for all polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Let $(a_{k})_{k \in \omega}$  be a sequence of positive integers such that $a_{k} < p_{k}$,  $a_{k} \leq a_{k+1}$ and $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} a_{k}=\infty$  where $p_{k}$ is the k-th prime number. Let $f(x)= \sum_{i=0}^{n}b_{i}X^{i}$ be any non-zero polynomial with $b_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Can we give a nice criteria that the sequence $(a_{k})$ is so that $f(a_{k})\equiv 0 \ (\text{mod} p_{k})$ for infinitely many primes $p_{k}$? (Editnote: Originally I asked if there is an example of such a sequence, but this was not really the intended goal.)

If $(a_{k})$ grows really slow, for example if we start with $1$ and just add one after exponentially increasing intervals, this can not be because the prime numbers outgrow $f(a_{k})$ in any case, so we don't reduce anything at a certain point and because a polynomial has only finitely many integer zeros we are done. But what if we choose for example $a_{k}=k$?

Comment: what if $f(x)=x$?

Comment: I misformulated the question, thank you! I meant if there can be a sequence such that  a polynomial exists such that.... I edited it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much freedom you have in the choice of the sequence and/or the polynomial but I think that you can find examples.

The simplest one I can think of is the sequence with $a_1 = 1$ and $a_k = \frac{p_k+1}{2}$, together with the polynomial $f(x) = 4x - 2$. Then you have that for all $k$, $f(a_k)$ is divisible by $p_k$.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. This works, but I think I would be interested in general criteria when this can not happen that are a bit stronger than "when it grows very very slow", thank you anyway!

Comment: Ok, I thought it was probably not the answer you expected, I see you have now updated your question. According to your comment shouldn't you phrase your question as: is it possible that for any polynomial $f$, $p_k$ divides $f(a_k)$ for only finitely many $p_k$?

Comment: I already know that this is possible by choosing $a_{k}$ to grow really really slow (so slow that every polynomial will have good reduction from some point on), the question is rather "Can one do better? And is there a general criteria?" For example, as stated, I would be interested if $a_{k}=k$ works. Even if I assume that the answer to the question for  general criteria will be "No."